# How to insert values with pre-defined column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

With SQL commands is it possible to pre-define a column value?

Let's assume I have `cars` and `car_model` table.

```
cars
    id
    name

car_model
    id
    name
    car_id
```

I want to put some `car_model` into table but like this.

```
INSERT INTO car_model (name, 1) VALUES ("A1"), ("A3"), ("A4")
```

Comment: No you can't. You have to do it like  `INSERT INTO car_model (name, car_id) VALUES ("A1", 1), ("A3", 1), ("A4", 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Pre-defining values" is basically the definition of "variable". So, you could use a variable.

```
SET @carID = 1;

INSERT INTO car_model (
     name
    ,car_id
) VALUES 
     ("A1", @carID)
    ,("A3", @carID)
    ,("A4", @carID)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting some constant or pre-define value , you can write your query like this:

```
INSERT INTO car_model (name,car_id ) VALUES ("A1","predefineVal"), ("A3","predefineVal"), ("A4","predefineVal");
```

where `predefineVal` is your pre-define a column value which you want to insert in your case is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `car_model` CHANGE `car_id` `car_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
```

Basically you will have to change the structure and set the default value to whatever you want.

THEN QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO car_model (name) VALUES ("A1"), ("A3"), ("A4");
```